# XACML - How to get the list of policies used in the decision?

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

The XACML standard states that if the request specifies the attribute `ReturnPolicyIdList="true"`, the PDP should return a list of all fully applicable policies and policy sets which were used in the decision.

I tried it with WSO IS 5.0 (with the latest service pack), but it seems to work only in a few cases. This is the first test policy: it permits write access to user `admin` on every file ending with `.dcm`.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="PolicyTest" Version="1.0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides">
    <Target></Target>
    <Rule RuleId="Rule1" Effect="Permit">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">^.*.dcm$</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="true" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"></Function>
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
    </Rule>
    <Rule RuleId="DefaultRule" Effect="Deny"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

And this is the example request (read access on `file.dcm`):

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" id="subject1">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" id="action1">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" id="resource1">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">file.dcm</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

If this is the only policy active in the PDP, the XACML response is correct (permit) and includes the list of IDs of all the policies used for the decision:

```
<Response>
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
        <PolicyIdentifierList>
            <PolicyIdReference>PolicyTest</PolicyIdReference>
        </PolicyIdentifierList>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

If I add any other policy (whose target is applicable for the request) I get an error. Specifically I tried to add a policy identical to the first one, except that it refers to write actions instead of read:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="PolicyTest" Version="1.0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides">
    <Target></Target>
    <Rule RuleId="Rule1" Effect="Permit">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">^.*.dcm$</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="true" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"></Function>
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
    </Rule>
    <Rule RuleId="DefaultRule" Effect="Deny"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

The log shows the following 2 errors (I omit the complete stack trace, but I can post it if you need it).

1st error:

```
TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-07-03 12:41:34,550] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getDecision
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

2nd error:

```
TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-07-03 12:41:34,558] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui.client.EntitlementServiceClient} - Error occurred while policy evaluation
```

How can I get it to work? Is there any setting to change or it's a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you just post the other policy ?  I guess you tried with same XACML request in above?

Comment: Hi, I've added the code of the second policy in the question. The request was the same. Thank you.

Comment: I have created an issue on WSO2's Jira: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3395

Answer (score 1):

According to the XACML standard, if you set ReturnPolicyIdList to true, then the PDP shall reply with the list of policy and policy set identifiers used in the request.

Here is a sample XACML 3.0 request (it's empty, i.e. it doesn't have any attributes)

```
<xacml-ctx:Request ReturnPolicyIdList="true" CombinedDecision="false" 
xmlns:xacml-ctx="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" >
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" >
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" >
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
</xacml-ctx:Request>
```

And here is a sample response.

```
<xacml-ctx:Response xmlns:xacml-ctx="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
  <xacml-ctx:Result>
    <xacml-ctx:Decision>Permit</xacml-ctx:Decision>
    <xacml-ctx:Status>
      <xacml-ctx:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
    </xacml-ctx:Status>
    <xacml-ctx:PolicyIdentifierList>
      <xacml-ctx:PolicyIdReference Version="1.0">http://www.axiomatics.com/automatic-unique-id/f8d86878-d458-472a-968d-1fd6c9655669</xacml-ctx:PolicyIdReference>
      <xacml-ctx:PolicySetIdReference Version="1.0">http://www.axiomatics.com/automatic-unique-id/21e6e472-d363-4ea9-990d-3fa03512b747</xacml-ctx:PolicySetIdReference>
    </xacml-ctx:PolicyIdentifierList>
  </xacml-ctx:Result>
</xacml-ctx:Response>
```

The response clearly conatins the list of policy identifiers inside the `PolicyIdentifierList` element.

I tested this on the [Axiomatics Policy Server](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/axiomatics-policy-server.html) and it works just fine. WSO2 IS is only a partial implementation so either it's a missing feature or a bug.

Comment: Tank you David, I think it's a bug. I will open an issue on WSO2's Jira. FYI, Axiomatics website is down right now.

Comment: We keep our bugs to the website :-)